# Is there a voice like the iPhone Voice Control voice for the Mac?

Tags: mac, iphone, voice

I really like the voice that repeats your voice commands back to you on the iPhone.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this voice is included as one of the voices on Mac OS X.  Does anyone know if this voice is available (3rd party or otherwise) for use on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this voice is Nuance "Samantha" and is also used by Siri and perhaps Ford Sync:

http://nextupdownloads.com/scansamples/samantha.wav

You can get this voice in Mac OS X Lion by following these steps:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/25/how-to-add-new-voices-to-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Yeah, Samantha was one of the new US English voices in Lion. It can be installed in the Speech preference pane.